# I deployed the war file to the tomcat but I can't start

Tags: tomcat, lifecycleexception

I deployed the war file to the tomcat but I can't start.

It gives error like that:

> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/fineract-provider]]

Comment: There will usually be a lot more info in the logs than this one line, try find them in the Tomcat log files.

Comment: there are a lot but I don't know which exactly will solve it

Comment: @xaquan Noone here can know that either.  If you want your issue solved, you need to find the relevant error in the logs.